# 'dependencies' cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang.Closure)

Tags: groovy, cucumber, build.gradle

I am using Groovy/Gradle with Cucumber framework. following are the versions

```
Groovy Version: 2.4.4

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.5
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2015-07-08 07:38:37 UTC

Build number: none
Revision:     093765bccd3ee722ed5310583e5ed140688a8c2b

Groovy:       2.3.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.7.0_17 (Oracle Corporation 23.7-b01)
OS:           Windows 8 6.2 amd64
```

I am getting this error when I try to run following

```
$ gradle clean idea

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Documents and Settings\Sudheerah\Documents\Sudheera\KBase\APDM\APIAutomation\build.gradle' line: 76

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'APIAutomation'.
> Could not find method groovy() for arguments [org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.4] on root project 'APIAutomation'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 35.237 secs
```

Below is the build.gradle file error line.

[image]

Stacktrace

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.MissingMethodException: Could not find method groovy() for arguments [org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.4] on root project 'APIAutomation'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.methodMissingException(AbstractDynamicObject.java:68)
```

Comment: so other than `clean idea` it works?  what does the stackstrace show?  what is your build.gradle?

Comment: Added more details with stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've applied the groovy plugin, you need to change your groovy dependency to a compile dependency.

The groovy dependency is the old way of setting up the groovy plugin

Comment: After got rid of error line, `>gradle clean idea ` worked